# Mongodb : $in operator vs lot of single queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I know MongoDB is able to handle a lot of requests/sec, but let's say I have to query a lot of documents of a collection given their _id; what sounds better: making a $in on the _id attribute with all the ids I want to get, or loop over findOne queries?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I would definitely go with using the $in query and providing a array of _ids.

Example:

```
db.collection.find({
    "key": {
        "$in": [
            ObjectId("xxx"),
            ObjectId("yyy"),
            ObjectId("zzz")
        ]
    }
})
```

Why?

- If you loop, there is a certain amount of setup and teardown for each query creating and exhausting cursors which would create overhead.
- If you are not doing this on a local machine it also creates tcp/ip overhead for every request. Locally you could use domain sockets.
- There is a index on "_id" created by default and collecting a group of documents to return in a batch request should be extremely fast so there is no need to break this up into smaller queries.

There's some additional documentation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-$in) if you want to check it out.

Comment: What if there's a lot of items in the $in...  say 100, or 1,000?

Comment: @ewindsor anything up to 1000 is usually ok. After that i'd reconsider the schema you have and start pre-computing the data.

Comment: can `$in` be used on an array of JSON objects?

Comment: Actually limit can be very high(even upto a million), but mainly depends upon the size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331549/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-parameters-passed-to-in-query-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

If You want to find directly with MongoChef UI you can use this query:

Field:{$in:[/Naveen Kumar/i, /Naveen/i, /Garshakurthy/i]}}