# Search for multiple values in Mongoose at the same time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of values, such as:

```
let items = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop"]
```

Sometimes there are a thousand items in this array, other times there are only a few.  I also have a series of documents with a schema including:

```
mongoose.Schema({
    name: { required: true, type: String }
})
```

Is there a *faster* way of querying for these items other than:

```
Model.find({ $or: [ items.map(item => ({ 'name': item })) ] }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb : $in operator vs lot of single queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219409/mongodb-in-operator-vs-lot-of-single-queries) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145523/mongodb-find-by-multiple-array-items

Comment: Oh hey, so it is.  I had my mind totally fixated on `$in` being querying for a single values when the schema is an array of values.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, that's what the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator is for:

```
Model.find({name: {$in: items}})
```

> The `$in` operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

Comment: Being top user with mongodb you should have marked it as duplicate

Comment: @DarkKnight I think it's actually a different enough question from the marked dupe as this involves $or vs multiple queries. Anyway, that was my reasoning.