# Passing multi parameter to find mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this collection

```
let tradeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    status: String,
});
var Trade = mongoose.model('Trade', tradeSchema, 'trade')

module.exports = Trade;
```

status can be 'a', 'b','c'
How can I find status 'a' and 'b' with single query?

```
Trade.find({
    status: 
  })
```

Comment: You could use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html#or) or [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html#in-aggregation)

Comment: @Joe I did it. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb : $in operator vs lot of single queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219409/mongodb-in-operator-vs-lot-of-single-queries) Just making this as duplicate !!