# Does Mongodb find $in has a limit

Tags: mongodb

is there a limit of the amount of items in the $in array.

E.g.

```
Collection.find({ field: { $in: [BIG ARRAY]} })
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18495467/6290463 this should help ! The answer is more detailed and the mechanism is deeply explained. I recommend this post marked as dupe rather than the other one.

Comment: Great totally helped.