# Is there a limit on how large $or array should be in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, optimization, find

I am trying to find users who have an id that could be one of 20,000 unique strings; there are over 2,000,000 possible strings; the response should come in no more than 30 seconds.

I was going to use a `.find{ $or: [<string1>, <string2> ... <string20,000>]` but I am worried about whether mongoose is designed to handle such large $or queries.

It would be great to know if anyone has any experience with such queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331549/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-parameters-passed-to-in-query-in-mongodb