# How large can an array be inside the $in operator?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

```js
db.Collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {field_A: {$in: [el_1, el_2, ...]}}}
])
```

What is the limit to [el_1, el_2, ...]? How many elements can it have? How large can it be in terms of megabytes?

Comment: I assume it must be less than 100 MiByte, see [Aggregation Pipeline Limits](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/)

Comment: I bet for 16MB :)

Comment: try refering this link . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331549/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-parameters-passed-to-in-query-in-mongodb

Comment: Yes, 16 MiByte seems to be correct. 100MiByte seems to be the threshold when a pipeline stage is written temporarily to disk instead of keeping the data in the RAM.