# What is the maximum size of an output collection in a stage of aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

I read that query cannot be more than 16mb in size in the aggregation pipeline.

What if a query outputs a collection of billions of documents? Is it simply going to crash then?

This seems rather limiting, that we can't query a collection beyond 16mb?

Comment: A query/collection may have many documents, 16 MiByte is the limit for one **document**, it is not the limit for the entire collection. A collection or a query output can be as large as you want (almost)

Comment: You asked so many questions about query limits and speed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603633/how-large-can-an-array-be-inside-the-in-operator, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596579/how-many-filter-conditions-can-a-query-have, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580135/expected-speed-performance-of-querying-a-sharded-collection-in-mongodb, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71552038/time-complexity-of-grouping-and-then-summarizing-in-mongodb - Do you have a specific problem with your application or do you just fear MongoDB will not be powerful enough?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Both are true. I do have a specific problem with my application, which is actually the main problem of the application and I do fear that MongoDB will not be powerful enough.

Comment: So is the limit for a collection 100mb, then? That's only several times more than the document limit then.

Comment: There is no practical limit for a collection, the only limit is your disc space. See [MongoDB at Baidu: Powering 100+ Apps Across 600 Nodes at PB Scale](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-at-baidu-powering-100-apps-across-600-nodes-at-pb-scale)