# BsonMaximumSizeExceededException thrown despite having no large documents

Tags: java, mongodb

I am currently building an index on a large text corpus. One of the indexes I have is a MongoDB collection consisting of documents with the following structure `{"_id": String, "ctr": Integer}`. This keeps count of how many times each word is in the corpus.

For further processing, I sometimes need to query the counters for given Strings, so in Java I have a `Set<String> ids`, and I basically need to query the "ctr" value for each entry which matches a string in ids.

My original code looked like this:

```
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(DB_NAME);
MongoCollection<Document> occurrences = db.getCollection(WORD_COUNT);
for (String id:ids) {
    Document kGramEntry = occurrences.find(eq("_id", id)).first();
    // check if null ... further processing
}
```

**This worked and returned all counters.** However, this was very slow, and I wondered if I could speed up the query.

I thought I could use the `Filters.in` option rather than `Filters.eq`, and therefore changed the query to this:

```
Document[] docs = occurrences.find(in("_id", ids)).into(new ArrayList<>()).toArray(new Document[0]);
```

When running this query, I now get a *BsonMaximumSizeExceededException: Document size of 18696125 is larger than maximum of 16793600*. thrown.
The thing is, I know for a fact the individual documents don't exceed 16Mb, so this error is hard to interpret.

I even tried another way:

```
FindIterable<Document> iter = occurrences.find(in("_id", ids));
try (MongoCursor<Document> cursor = iter.iterator()) {
       List<Document> elems = new ArrayList<>();
       while (cursor.hasNext()) {
           elems.add(cursor.next());
       }
            
       docs = elems.toArray(new Document[0]);
}
```

but the same exception is thrown.

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening and what I could do to fix it?
I thank you all in advance for any tips or help.
Nathan (edits:font change)

Comment: [Class BsonMaximumSizeExceededException](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/5.0/apidocs/bson/org/bson/BsonMaximumSizeExceededException.html) describes as "An exception indicating a failure to serialize a BSON document due to it exceeding the maximum size.".  But, this discussion may be helpful: https://groups.google.com/g/mongodb-user/c/uv12-TlQQW8?pli=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After diving into this, I am now confident I know what went wrong. It turns out that when you create a query for your MongoCollection, the query is also of type `Document`.

Consequently, if your query looks like this:

```
collection.find(in("_id", batch))
```

and `batch` is a huge array, then chances are your query document will be larger than 16Mb, resulting in the error that was thrown.

The MongoDB [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) states that "*It is recommended that you limit the number of parameters passed to the $in operator to tens of values. Using hundreds of parameters or more can negatively impact query performance.*" so I probably should have paid more attention to that warning anyways.

For a better understanding of how query size evolves, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331549/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-parameters-passed-to-in-query-in-mongodb) thread is very helpful.