# How do I do this query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

Suppose I have many "posts" in a database as documents, each with an "author" attribute.

I want to execute a query like this:

```
posts.find(author IN 3, 5, 733, 144, 66, 3457 , 22, 156, 344...)
```

Basicaly, I want to find all posts where author is ..... and then give a hundred ids.

What's the most efficient way to do this in Mongo?

Answer (score 3):

Use Mongo's `$in` operator:

```
posts.find({"author" : {"$in":[3, 5, 733, 144, 66, 3457 , 22, 156, 344]}});
```

Here's the reference: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in

You should probably index the author field too: `posts.ensureIndex({author:1});`

Comment: Is this efficient? What if people are following thousands?

Comment: @TIMEX - I did some tests recently, which seemed to indicate that there is a "sweet spot" regarding the number of values in an $in clause (i.e. lower amount of values/higher number of queries vs higher number of values/lower number of queries) - see my answer here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157265/is-it-ok-to-query-a-mongodb-multiple-times-per-request/5157425